# Append string to array and join back into string

Tags: jinja2

I'm using Home Assistant templates, which run on Jinja2 script.

I have a group of entities (`states.group.doors`) that  have attribute `battery_level`. I want to build an array of entities with `battery_level` < `min_battery level` and display as a string separated by commas.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax. Two questions:

1. Is there just a better way overall to create a list that is filtered for `battery_level < min_battery_level` rather than building an array like I am?
2. If not, then there must be something wrong with the way I am building this array. Can someone spot it?

Thanks for the help.

The following code does successfully detect `battery_level < 98` and display `true` if anything meets that criteria, so I'm almost there.

```
{% set min_battery_level = 98 -%}
{% set ns = namespace(found=false, entities=[]) -%}
{% set entities = [] -%}
{% for entity_id in states.group.doors.attributes.entity_id -%}
  {% set parts = entity_id.split('.') -%}
  {% if (state_attr(entity_id, 'battery_level') | replace("%","") | int) < min_battery_level -%}
    {% set ns.found = true -%}
    {% set entities = entities + [entity_id] -%}
  {% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
{{ ns.found }}
{{ entities | join(' ') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp... kept playing with it and got it working as follows:

```
{% set min_battery_level = 98 -%}
{% set ns = namespace(found=false, entities = []) -%}
{% for entity_id in states.group.doors.attributes.entity_id -%}
  {% set name = state_attr(entity_id, 'friendly_name') | string -%}
  {% set battery = state_attr(entity_id, 'battery_level') | replace("%","") | int -%}
  {% if (battery) < min_battery_level -%}
    {% set ns.found = true -%}
    {% set ns.entities = ns.entities + [name+' ('+battery|string+'%)'] -%}
  {% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
{{ ns.found }}
{{ ns.entities | join(', ') }}
```